# Qmake in cygwin not found for QT5

Tags: cygwin, qt5, qmake

I tried to install QT5 within cygwin and succeeded. I am also getting the Xorg menu with `Cygwin/X` for the designer.

But I could not find the qmake.exe for QT5. I only get the following files in the cygwin select package window

[image]

And also it shows `mingw64-xxxx-qt4-qmake.exe` not `qmake.exe`

unfortunately I could not sacrifice cygwin and go for a windows distribution. Should I build Qt5 from source code ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

qmake-qt5 belongs to libQt5Core-devel

As usual the search engine is available at

https://cygwin.com/packages/

Comment: After installing `libQt5Core-devel`, I needed to set up a symlink: `ln -s /usr/bin/qmake-qt5 /usr/bin/qmake`